# How to redirect an api (token) authenticated user (in a flutter app) to session based auth (in a flutter web view)?

Tags: php, authentication, webview, flutter, session-cookies

What I want to achieve: let's say I have an Api (token) authenticated user then once this user click a button I wanted to open a web-view and authenticate him on a session based auth.
[image]

What I did till now (many solutions and propositions):

1. use `url_launcher`:

   - open a browser on click `launch(url)`
   - send a token (GET params) to the backend server
   - authenticate the user and redirect back
     Working well BUT bad Ux, user needs to go between browser and the app!
2. use 1`flutter_webview_plugin` or 2`webview_flutter`:

   - open a webview on click 
       1

     ```dart
     class __WebWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return WebviewScaffold(
          url: url + "?token=${userManager.token}",
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: Text('Space'),
          ),
          withZoom: true,
          withLocalStorage: true,
          hidden: true,
          initialChild: Container(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            child: const Center(
              child: Text('Loading....'),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
     }
     ```

     2

     ````dart
     class WebWidget extends StatelessWidget {
       WebWidget({this.url});

       final String url;

       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Scaffold(
           appBar: AppBar(
             title: Text('Votre Espace '),
           ),
           body: WebView(
             initialUrl: url + "?token=${userManager.token}",
             javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
           ),
         );
       }
     }
     ```
     ````
   - send a token (GET params) to the backend server
   - authenticate the user and redirect back
     Not Working !

I suspected that the webview does not support the cookies !

> In the backend, i'm using laravel (php7) and Apache server.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using flutter, I'd recommend the [Flutter Web Auth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_auth#-readme-tab-) plugin for authenticating a user with a web service. It can be used for any web flow that can redirect to a custom scheme.

It automatically redirects you to your app with authenticated tokens (If your app is Android then remember to edit the AndroidManifest.xml as per the instructions given in the [README.md](https://github.com/LinusU/flutter_web_auth/blob/master/readme.md) file)

Comment: I've tried using this library, and it doesn't seem to work. Questions on stackoverflow and github also go unanswered

Comment: Did you figure this out?